# レコードの分割と結合について

Tags: python, python3

10000Byteあるレコードを1000Byte毎に分割すると、1000Byteのレコードが10個できますが最初の１つ目のレコードはそのままで以降の9個のレコードについては先頭から10Byteを削除し990Byteにして
その後、分割したレコードを結合したいのですが、簡単でよい方法は御座いませんでしょうか。

イメージ
1234567890|1234567890|1234567890分割
1234567890| 234567890| 234567890先頭を削除
1234567890234567890234567890結合

Comment: 簡単で良い方法かどうかは分かりませんが、「10000Byteあるレコード」が文字列であると仮定して、`''.join([record[(i and (i+10)):i+1000] for i in range(0, 10000, 1000)])` でしょうか。

Comment: 確認です。質問された方はpythonで行いたいのですね。pythonでなくてもよいなら、ddコマンドを使うのが簡単だと思います。

Answer (score 0):

以下のような感じでどうでしょうか。
質問文に記載のイメージを参考に、最初は10byte、それ以降は10byteのレコードの先頭1byteを除き、9byteを結合しています。

nを1000, mを10に変えれば、もともとの質問のコードになるかと。

```
data = '123456789012345678901234567890'.encode('utf-8') # イメージのデータ

n = 10 # レコードのバイト数（10byte）
m = 1  # 先頭の不要なバイト数(1byte)

#最初のnバイトは取り出しておく
ret = data[0:n]

#元データからのデータ取得と結果データへの結合
for i in range(n, len(data), n):
    ret = ret + data[i+m:i+n]

print(ret) # 結果をstdoutへ出力
```